# Convergence in distribution and taking sqrt of random variables

Tags: probability

If $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables converging in distribution to a chi-squared distribution with degree of freedom being $\nu$, will $\sqrt{X_n}$ converges in distribution to the sqrt of the squared sum of $\nu$ iid standard normal random variables? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\{Xn\}$ converges in distribution to $X $if and only if 
$\mathbf{E}f(Xn) → \mathbf{E}ƒ(X)$ for all bounded, continuous functions ƒ;

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution)

So it is true.